# How to handle client getting disconnected?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telegram-bot, telethon

I am using telethon to write a script.

```
async def main():
    client = TelegramClient('session',api_id,api_hash)
    await client.connect()
    await client.start()
    @client.on(events.NewMessage())
    async def handler(event):
        print(event.messsage.text)
    await client.run_untill_disconnected()
asyncio.run(main())
```

The code works fine for normal use. It fetches updates and prints them. But, I am in search of an special event.
Say, while the client is running and the user terminates this session from the telegram app forcefully,
then my script stops working which is very obvious. Now, The problem is that when session is terminated I want to handle that event(or may be error) in **realtime** in my code, so that it starts doing some other task. How do I do it..?

Comment: could you give a concrete example for what you want the other tasks is? Your question is quite open ended at the moment

Comment: The exception should raise through `run_until_disconnected`, so write your code in the `except`.

Comment: @Lonami I tried to except but it doesn't seem to work in real time. The exception `AuthKeyUnregisteredError` was received but it took more than 2 minutes to receive it. Is there a way to get this client disconnect update in almost realtime..?